# PHP search from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've a search function in PHP/MySQL that works fine as long as I only search from one table. The problem is that I need to search one table and display info from that but also display two parts from another table. Using this code I get an `Notice: Trying to get property of non-obect` error. My PHP code is this:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $link->escape_string($_GET['search']);
    $query = $link->query("SELECT l.Id, l.ImageId, l.Subject, l.Level, l.Aim, i.NameImg, i.AltImg FROM LessonPlans l, Images i WHERE Subject LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Level LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Aim LIKE '%".$search."%' AND Language='English'");

if($query->num_rows){        
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()){

    echo '<div class="col s6 m4 l3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="../mlslp/assets/img/'.$r->NameImg.'" alt="'. $r->AltImg.'">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 truncate tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="800" data-tooltip="'.$r->Subject.'">'.$r->Subject.'</span>
                    <p class="blue-text">'.$r->Level.'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="lessonplan.php?Id='.$r->Id.'">Open Lesson Plan</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">'.$r->Subject.'<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>'.$r->Aim.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';

        }
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to get around the problem with that two tables don't send an object? I'm not sure if it's the query or the if/while statements that are wrong.

Comment: Do you have any common field in each table? like primary key and foreign key?

Comment: yes, they are joined through `ImageId`

Comment: Where are you initializing the $link variable? are you sure is an mysql resource?

Comment: yes, the `$link`comes from the database which I have required (`require_once("db_link.inc.php");`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both table have the same name ImageId, then try the beloq query

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT l.Id, l.ImageId, l.Subject, l.Level, l.Aim, i.NameImg, i.AltImg FROM LessonPlans l join Images i on i.ImageId=l.ImageId WHERE Subject LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Level LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Aim LIKE '%".$search."%' AND Language='English'");
```

> i.ImageId -> Image id of table Images table
>
> l.ImageId -> Image id of LessonPlans table

Comment: Still get the `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in` with this change

Comment: Please run the sql code in phpmyadmin and check whether any result coming

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the query but in the way it handles objects. Unfurtunately my php level isn't good enough at the moment to understand  why!

Comment: What `$link` represents?

Comment: `$link` is the connection to the database. That is the same on the rest of the site so that is not the problem....

Comment: I got this message in phpMyAdmin **#1052 - Column 'Language' in where clause is ambiguous**

Comment: @Håkan, Try the query with actual values in phpmyadmin and look what result is coming

Comment: @Håkan, you have to specify the alias name for "Language" too. Mysql don't know from which table it is. You have to add either "l.Language" or "i.Language"

Comment: Silly me... It just changed the error message now instead to: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Name in /home/hani0008/public_html/mlslp/search.php on line 24

Notice: Use of undefined constant Img - assumed 'Img' in /home/hani0008/public_html/mlslp/search.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Alt in /home/hani0008/public_html/mlslp/search.php on line 24

Notice: Use of undefined constant img - assumed 'img' in /home/hani0008/public_html/mlslp/search.php on line 24
0"> `

Comment: Error is describing well. Google it and find solution

Comment: @Håkan, If the query is working, then please up vote and accept the answer. So that it will be easy for others to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hyphen in your database names.

In SQL i.Name-img should be treated as i.Name minus img

and in PHP it's the same.

You can't call $r->Name-Img because it's treated like $r->Name minus constant Img (or string).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited that. Didn't help in this question though...